# Unable to convert string to integer from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need help on determining what cause the error of my code. 
"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Undergraduate' to data type int." when i hit the ADD Button. 
I'm struggling to find what went wrong. It worked at first but suddenly, the error alway occur.

This is the full code;

```
private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (SqlConnection conncurr = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionstring))
            using (SqlCommand cmdcurr = new SqlCommand("curriculumadd", conncurr))
            {
                try
                {
                    conncurr.Open();
                    var newaccountparam1 = new SqlParameter("@dccode", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    var newaccountparam2 = new SqlParameter("@dcdesc", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    var newaccountparam3 = new SqlParameter("@currtitle", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    var newaccountparam4 = new SqlParameter("@units", SqlDbType.Int);
                    var newaccountparam5 = new SqlParameter("@labunits", SqlDbType.Int);
                    var newaccountparam6 = new SqlParameter("@lecunits", SqlDbType.Int);
                    var newaccountparam7 = new SqlParameter("@yearlevel", SqlDbType.Int);
                    var newaccountparam8 = new SqlParameter("@sem", SqlDbType.Int);
                    var newaccountparam9 = new SqlParameter("@labhrs", SqlDbType.Int);
                    var newaccountparam10 = new SqlParameter("@lechrs", SqlDbType.Int);
                    var newaccountparam11 = new SqlParameter("@acadlevel", SqlDbType.Int);
                    var newaccountparam12 = new SqlParameter("@subjcode", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    var newaccountparam13 = new SqlParameter("@subjdesc", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    var newaccountparam14 = new SqlParameter("@subjcat", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    var newaccountparam15 = new SqlParameter("@curreffectvty", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    newaccountparam1.Value = txtcoursecode.Text;
                    newaccountparam2.Value = txtdcourse.Text;
                    newaccountparam3.Value = currtitle;
                    newaccountparam4.Value = totalunits;
                    newaccountparam5.Value = txtlabunits.Text;
                    newaccountparam6.Value = txtlecunits.Text;
                    newaccountparam7.Value = yearlevel;
                    newaccountparam8.Value = semestr;
                    newaccountparam9.Value = labhrs;
                    newaccountparam10.Value = lecthrs;
                    newaccountparam11.Value = acadlevel;
                    newaccountparam12.Value = txtsubjcode.Text;
                    newaccountparam13.Value = txtdesctitle.Text;
                    newaccountparam14.Value = cmbsubjfield.Text;
                    newaccountparam15.Value = txteffectivity.Text;
                    cmdcurr.Parameters.Add(newaccountparam1);
                    cmdcurr.Parameters.Add(newaccountparam2);
                    cmdcurr.Parameters.Add(newaccountparam3);
                    cmdcurr.Parameters.Add(newaccountparam4);
                    cmdcurr.Parameters.Add(newaccountparam5);
                    cmdcurr.Parameters.Add(newaccountparam6);
                    cmdcurr.Parameters.Add(newaccountparam7);
                    cmdcurr.Parameters.Add(newaccountparam8);
                    cmdcurr.Parameters.Add(newaccountparam9);
                    cmdcurr.Parameters.Add(newaccountparam10);
                    cmdcurr.Parameters.Add(newaccountparam11);
                    cmdcurr.Parameters.Add(newaccountparam12);
                    cmdcurr.Parameters.Add(newaccountparam13);
                    cmdcurr.Parameters.Add(newaccountparam14);
                    cmdcurr.Parameters.Add(newaccountparam15);
                    cmdcurr.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmdcurr.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                finally
                {
                    conncurr.Close();
                    conncurr.Dispose();
                    userlogsmonitor.ActiveForm.Refresh();
                }
            }
        }
```

Code for converting string to integer;

```
private void cmbacadlevel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (cmbacadlevel.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim())
            {
                case "Undergraduate":
                    acadlevel = 1;
                    break;
                case "Masteral":
                    acadlevel = 2;
                    break;
                case "Doctorate":
                    acadlevel = 3;
                    break;
                case "Senior High School":
                    acadlevel = 4;
                    break;
            }
```

I tried editing the code but it seems not lucky enough. Can you please scrutinize my code and try to give an idea on how to deal with it?

Comment: It won't fix your problem, but notice that you can use one line instead of three for each parameter: `cmdcurr.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dccode", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtcoursecode.Text;`

Comment: There isn't enough code for full context here, but I notice the error mentions "varchar".  That's a database type, not a c# type.  That means the error is happening in your Sql Command function.  I don't think your SelectedIndexChanged() function is even relevant here.  It sounds like you're accidentally passing a string to your sql command function when it expects an int.

Comment: I see that `cmbacadlevel` is a `ComboBox` control, can you provide which line that conversion exception exactly thrown? Also `SelectedIndexChanged` event seems irrelevant because `acadlevel` is already assigned to integer value.

Answer (score 0):

Verify following things

- Order and type of parameter is same as in the stored procedure
- Either use breakpoint to verify values of int parameters
- Or use SQL Server Profiler to to check if int parameters have valid values.